# How to make a circle shape label in Window Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As you all know, a label is usually in a square or rectangle shape. I really need to make circle shaped label. Can anyone please tell me is this possible or at least point me in a right direction?

Sorry, just to make things clear. I want a circle shaped label. Not just drawing a circle on the screen.

Comment: Homework? If so, please add a homework tag.

Comment: Is your question about drawing a circle in Windows Forms or writing text which follows a circle path ?

Comment: It is not for a homework. I need to make a circle label. A circle shape label instead of square or rectangle shape ones.

Comment: Do you mean horizontal text wrapped to fit within a circle, or text that is rendered along a circular path?

Comment: You can make a composite Control consisting of a drawn graphics cicle, as Micah Armatrout mentioned, encircling a regular Label. It's not clear what sort of behavior you want (if you want multiple lines, where you want the text to start, left to right, or top to bottom, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded edges in picturebox C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731855/rounded-edges-in-picturebox-c-sharp)

Comment: It is nothing to do with text or anything like that. All I want is simple I want my label to became a circle shape. lblLabel = a circle shape. That way I can set background color of the circle label.

Comment: Although it is not really perfect, but it helped! Thanks:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
```

Comment: I want only a circle label. A label but circle shape Label

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling CreateGraphics on PaintEventArgs?

Answer (score 14):

You can set the Region property of your Label :

```
var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
path.AddEllipse(0, 0, label1.Width, label1.Height);

this.label1.Region = new Region(path);
```