# Label with smooth rounded corners

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls, panel

[image: 2 labels in windows form]

Both labels have `AutoSize` true & `TextAlign` MiddleCenter.

**How can also label2 show smooth borders?**

Here is the test code for handlers `Form.Load(...)` & `Form.Paint(...)`:

```
int _cornerRadius = 10;
Point _locationLabel2;

// Form.Load(...)
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Step 1: Cut the label regions (seems to be ok, result is the same for both labels)
    GraphicsPath graphicsPath = _getRoundPath(label1.ClientRectangle, _cornerRadius);
    label1.Region = new Region(graphicsPath);
    graphicsPath = _getRoundPath(label2.ClientRectangle, _cornerRadius);
    label2.Region = new Region(graphicsPath);

    _locationLabel2 = this.PointToClient(label2.Parent.PointToScreen(label2.Location));
}

// Form.Paint(...)
private void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(label1.BackColor, 3.0f))
    {
        // Step 2: Smooth the label borders (ok only for label1)
        _drawRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics, pen, label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y, 
                              label1.ClientRectangle.Width, label1.ClientRectangle.Height, _cornerRadius);
        _drawRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics, pen, _locationLabel2.X, _locationLabel2.Y,
                              label2.ClientRectangle.Width, label2.ClientRectangle.Height, _cornerRadius);
    }
}

// Helper 1/3
private static GraphicsPath _getRoundPath(Rectangle rectangle, int radius)
{
    int x = rectangle.X;
    int y = rectangle.Y;
    int width = rectangle.Width;
    int height = rectangle.Height;

    radius = radius << 1;

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    if (radius > 0)
    {
        if (radius > height) radius = height;
        if (radius > width) radius = width;
        path.AddArc(x, y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
    }
    else
    {
        path.AddRectangle(rectangle);
    }

    return path;
}

// Helper 2/3
private void _drawRoundedRectangle(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius)
{
    RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
    GraphicsPath path = _generateRoundedRectangle(graphics, rectangle, radius);
    SmoothingMode old = graphics.SmoothingMode;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = old;
}

// Helper 3/3
private static GraphicsPath _generateRoundedRectangle(Graphics graphics, RectangleF rectangle, int radius)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    float diameter = radius * 2.0F;
    SizeF sizeF = new SizeF(diameter, diameter);
    RectangleF arc = new RectangleF(rectangle.Location, sizeF);

    path.AddArc(arc, 180, 90); 
    arc.X = rectangle.Right - diameter;
    path.AddArc(arc, 270, 90);
    arc.Y = rectangle.Bottom - diameter;
    path.AddArc(arc, 0, 90);
    arc.X = rectangle.Left;
    path.AddArc(arc, 90, 90); 
    path.CloseFigure();

    return path;
}
```

<sub>Main code parts are from [Arun Reginald Zaheeruddin](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/gdi-plus/extendedgraphicsii.aspx)</sub>

Comment: __Not possible__, really. `Regions` do not allow anti-aliasing, hence the SmoothingMode will not allow any anti-aliased pixels.. Depending on your layout you may be able to owner-draw them, though as you do in label1..

Comment: Try using `path.AddBezier` rather than `AddArc`.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347576/how-to-make-a-circle-shape-label-in-window-form

Comment: @helrich: There is no difference between them at all.

Comment: @Ricky: Not a duplicate: The accepted answer there is all wrong and the others are doing what he already has. This is not about rounded corners but about smoothness. No smoothness for Regions. Period.

Comment: Do you really need changing region? You can draw your round label that supports `Transparent` back color with smooth round corners simply like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39230299/3110834).

Comment: As mentioned by Taw, regions are not smooth, so you can not achieve smooth round edge using regions, if for any reason the way which built-in transparent background works in windows forms is not what you are looking for, you can cheat transparent layers using [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36102074/3110834).

Comment: Don't use a control.  Just draw what you want.

Comment: @LarsTech: Sounds smart, will pick it up when my next drawing problem appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230299/3135228) by @Reza Aghaei.

**Solution**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class RoundLabel : Label
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public Color _BackColor { get; set; }

    public RoundLabel()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (var graphicsPath = _getRoundRectangle(this.ClientRectangle))
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(_BackColor))
                e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, graphicsPath);
            using (var pen = new Pen(_BackColor, 1.0f))
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, graphicsPath);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, this.Font, this.ClientRectangle, this.ForeColor);
        }
    }

    private GraphicsPath _getRoundRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        int cornerRadius = 15; // change this value according to your needs
        int diminisher = 1;
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - cornerRadius - diminisher, rectangle.Y, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width - cornerRadius - diminisher, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - cornerRadius - diminisher, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height - cornerRadius - diminisher, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseAllFigures();
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked the first time but after that I'm getting a normal label although I'm trying to create a round one. VS2013.

Comment: @n.jmurov: Is your problem still there?

Comment: Yes. I might try and attach a screenshot later. In the code they're RoundLabels but on the screen they're normal. I don't believe there's an error in code since it worked the first time.

Comment: Nice solution: it looks quite "natural" on WinForms

Comment: @n.jmurov: I've uploaded a little sample project (VS 2010, .net 4.0), hope it helps ==> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sOSdWzK9AZTEpxbjc1YldZNWM/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-FkA-zb46cd-Mx3PkH_uTqw