# Load picture to circle picturebox

Tags: c#

`PictureBox` in C# is rectangular. I want to load picture in `PictureBox` in circle to manipulated it.

How to do it?

Comment: check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731855/rounded-edges-in-picturebox-c-sharp possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/603084bb-1aae-45d1-84ae-8544386d58fd/rounded-corners-on-a-picturebox-in-c?forum=winforms):-

```
[Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
int d = 50;
gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - d, r.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - d, r.Y + r.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y + r.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
pictureBox1.Region = new Region(gp);][2]
```