# Can I do a circle Picture Box in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm designing an UI in WinForms with C#. What i want to do is to change the picture box form to something different to a rectangle. Is it possible?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731855/rounded-edges-in-picturebox-c-sharp